# Upload renamed package in Github

Tags: eclipse, git, package, rename, git-push

I have renamed my package in Eclipse and also changed all references of the old name. I had initially pushed my project into github with the old package name. Now that I have renamed my package, how should I push my code ? Will a normal push ( into the same branch containing the previous code) be fine or should I do something else to upload my project with its new package name ?

Answer (score 0):

Version control (git in your case) is designed to track all sorts of changes including renamed files, etc. assuming you committed them properly - which I assume Eclipse helped you do. There is no reason you would not be fine to push those changes to github, assuming when referring to packages you mean in the [Java sense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_packages) or something similar, and not some external (to your repository) Eclipse abstraction I did not successfully Google. This is why you are using version control! :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had to change the urlof my remote repo in Eclipse and then do a commit and push and it worked.